# How to append string and variable in terraform

Tags: terraform, fusionauth

How can I concatenate string and a variable in terraform. I am using terraform version 1.7

Name = "Test (Environment_Name)" where environment_name will be test,stage and prod.

```
    resource "fusionauth_tenant" "tanant" {
  name = "Test (Environment_name)"
  email_configuration {
    default_from_name                 = "FusionAuth [Environment_name]"
    verification_email_template_id    = fusionauth_email.verification_template.id
  }
```

Comment: `"${var}-some-string-${var2}-some-string"`

Comment: will that work? how can I do using local?

Comment: `"${local.value}-some-string"`, yes it will work.

Comment: can you provide me with the code?

Comment: Well, I already did it. but let me post an answer then.

Comment: okay, thanks for posting the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Examples of how to append a string and a variable.

settings.tf:

```
locals {
  bucket_prefix = "test-bucket"
}
```

And then you want to create three S3 buckets.

s3.tf:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "a" {
  bucket = "${local.bucket_prefix}-app"
}
//name = test-bucket-app


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = local.bucket_prefix
}
//name = test-bucket


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "c" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"
}
//name = my-bucket
```

If you want to append a variable from `var` or get a name from a resource, it will follow the same pattern. It will always be:

```
"${var.name.value}-my-string"
```

Comment: local.var will be `Test` and my environment will be var.env_name, right

Comment: You mean `"${var.value1}-${var.value2}"`?

Comment: Yeah, I posted `value` but I did change it to make it easy to understand the concept of using two vars. I've deleted the comment, thanks @Marcin.

Comment: By the way, no matter if you are using variables, locals, or resources attributes, the rule is the same, if you need to append it to a string, you need to put it as I've posted in the answer.

Comment: ${local.tenant_prefix}${var.env_name} - like this

Comment: how can I add spaces in between the two vars

Comment: `"${local.tenant_prefix} ${var.env_name}"`  -- just it. -- But you need to know if the resource that you are creating, accepts space in its attribute, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: can you help me with another query regarding templates in terraform posted in a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69555659/how-can-i-variablize-a-template-and-text-file-in-terraform