# How can I variablize a template and text file in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I have this template named : email-passwordless.ar.html.ftl

Its content is as follows:

```
[#setting url_escaping_charset="UTF-8"]
[#assign url = "https://google.com/auth/prod/${code}" /]

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
<head>
```

The resource using this template is :

```
resource "fusionauth_email" "passwrodless_template" {
  name                  = var.passwordless_email_template_name
  localized_subjects = {
    "ar" = var.email_passwordless_localized_subjects
  }
  localized_html_templates = {
    "ar" = file("${path.module}/email-templates/email-passwordless.ar.html.ftl")
  }
}
```

The template will be used across different environments and hence its URL will be different for each environment. How can I make the URL in the template as variable and pass its value in resource or something similar to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the [templatefile function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html) for this use case. You can create  the `email-passwordless.ar.html.tmpl` file in the same path as your current file:

```
[#setting url_escaping_charset="UTF-8"]
[#assign url = "${url}" /]

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
<head>
```

where we replace your already named string type variable `code` with `url` for the entire url. After assigning a value to `var.url` in your Terraform config, its value can be passed to the template renderer through the `templatefile` function arguments:

```
localized_html_templates = {
  "ar" = templatefile("${path.module}/email-templates/email-passwordless.ar.html.tmpl", { url = var.url })
}
```

Comment: `i want to replace google.com with a different url, how can be done, {code} will remain like this only

Comment: or for simplicity I would like to replace  entire this "https://google.com/auth/prod/${code}" with a new url specific for each env

Comment: How can I do that

Comment: @cloudbud Ok if you want the entire url instead of just what you designated with `code`, then I updated the answer for that.

Comment: Hey, your code isn't working ```│ Invalid value for "vars" parameter: vars map does not contain key "code", referenced at ../modules/fusionauth/email-templates/email-passwordless.ar.html.tmpl:2,26-30.```

Comment: @cloudbud There is no `var.code` in my answer. You wanted the entire url so I changed it. I am not sure how that error is thrown, but it is outside of my answer.

Comment: Yeah but if you see my url it has ${code} which is not a var but part of url so how can it be made work

Comment: so my actual url is https://nonprod.com/auth/prod/${code} where code should appear like this, if I variablize it  gives me error │
```│ A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.```